# Is the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file relevant on Rocky Linux using EFI?

Tags: grub2, uefi

On all my system (efi and classic) I usually use

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

on Rocky Linux 8 I see on efi the grub.cfg is located on

```
 /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg
```

Is the file /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
useless on Rocky Linux using EFI?

Comment: Do not know Rocky, but UEFI boots using the ESP. Normal boot process with grub is that UEFI finds file in ESP defined by GUID/partUUID. see `sudo efibootmgr -v`  And then  grub in ESP uses grub.cfg for most installs to find the full grub.cfg in your install using UUID. If you have lsblk `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`

Comment: Add this comment as answer so I can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know Rocky.

UEFI boots using the ESP. Normal boot process with grub is that UEFI uses file in ESP defined by GUID/partUUID. see

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

And then grub in ESP uses grub.cfg for most installs to find the full grub.cfg in your install using UUID. If you have lsblk

```
lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid
```